# Magento how get options with some additional information

Tags: sql, join, magento

I am working with options, to add some additional info like image. and I saved this data to my own table with option_type_id and option_id. now on frontend I would like to join my own table data to default options. so these options come with image info.

```
$_option->getValues()
```

this function returns option data, now I have to reach the implementation of this function where it generate the query so I could add join to retrieve my own data with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what i got success from.

i overridden the resource collection of product

```
 class MYC_COPSwatch_Model_Resource_Product_Option_Collection extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Option_Collection{        

     public function addValuesToResult($storeId = null)
{
    if ($storeId === null) {
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    }
    $optionIds = array();
    foreach ($this as $option) {
        $optionIds[] = $option->getId();
    }
    if (!empty($optionIds)) {
        /** @var $values Mage_Catalog_Model_Option_Value_Collection */
        $values = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option_value')
            ->getCollection()                
            ->addTitleToResult($storeId)
            ->addPriceToResult($storeId)                

            ->addSwatchToResult($storeId)   //USED Join in this function             

            ->setOrder('sort_order', self::SORT_ORDER_ASC)
            ->setOrder('title', self::SORT_ORDER_ASC);

        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $optionId = $value->getOptionId();
            if($this->getItemById($optionId)) {
                $this->getItemById($optionId)->addValue($value);
                $value->setOption($this->getItemById($optionId));
            }
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

might be save time for someone.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see a clean way to do this.

Here is a dirty way:
Rewrite`Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Option` and add this function below.
Modify it with you join. however the join to you table would then be done for **every** product option. You will need to check for somekind of a flag and only add your join if this flag is set.

```
protected function _getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object)
{ 
    $select = parent::_getLoadSelect($field, $value, $object);
    if("do your check here"){
         $select->join('your table')
    }      
    return $select;
}
```

Comment: there is no such function in this class. and i have to join values not options, if i am right.

Comment: yes thats because `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Option` is extending `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract` there you will find the function, i will update my answer